# Add to cart for out of stock products

Tags: addtocart

I'm trying to get the **Add to cart** button to appear on products that are **Out of stock**. I've already set the System->Configuration->Catalog->Inventory->Backorders=**Allow Qty Below 0**

My store previously did not allow back orders. If I add the following code:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
```

The **Add to cart** appears on products that are **In Stock** but does not appear on products that are **Out of stock**.

**Troubleshooting:**

- Inventory > Stock Options > Display Out of Stock Products is set to **YES**
- Cleared all cache **var/cache**, **var/session**, restarted **httpd**
- Re-indexed all indexes
- Tried using default theme with same result

Still no success and as pointed out by [*Simon*](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/142/simon) this is not a new problem. What I am having trouble understanding is why there would be the option(s) to **Allow back orders** and **Allow stock level quantities to go bellow 0** and not have the **Add to cart** button.

**UPDATE II**

I downloaded and installed the latest version of Magento, did a fresh installation, added 2 products, one with inventory (In stock) the other without (Out of stock) have set **Allow Qty Bellow 0**, **Show products out of stock** and the same problem.

**Would appreciate an explanation and a solution to this problem.**

Comment: Tried backorders in magento ?

Comment: @TBIInfotech yes I did, I mentioned it above thank you.

Comment: I have answered to this, have you checked changing setting from manage products?

Comment: Yes you answered but I already mentioned I did this in my question. I have checked these settings and the suggestions from Pronto and Amsty; I believe the problem is with the magento code. I cannot get the add to cart button to appear for products that are out of stock with the code I provided <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?> and I turning off manage stock is not an option as I have scripts handling this, furthermore it incorrectly tells visitors the product is in stock when in fact it is not.

Comment: There are two settings for backorders, one from system config, and from from manage products >Inventory, both are done?

Comment: Correct - both settings are set and the store was re-indexed.

Comment: Try clearing cache via var folder, or remove any custom coding done, or try using custom theme check if it is working for default theme

Comment: Great suggestions; manually cleared cache, restarted appropriate services, switched to default theme, no add to cart button; unless the code needs to be modified on the default theme so there is no **if** condition check?

Comment: which magento version are you working on?

Comment: version 1.8.0.0

Comment: By the way it would of course help if you would edit your question to reflect all the information you gave in the comments (Magento version, configuration settings).

Comment: I tried the solution from user_8934789123478912894812641, I changed the minimum to -9999 in stead of -1, ok the button displays and now you can add the product to the cart, BUT checkout will not accept that and send you back to the shopping cart (Magento 1.9), and even the product stock was changed to "Not in Stock" (so corrected this, but the button is still visible) .. so this is not a solution unfortunately .. the stock can only go below 0 for backorders but first have the stock to be greater 0 .. in other shops like opencart etc. this all is not a problem .. BUT there are extensions they c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Solution**

After much, much testing here is how you can have the **Add to cart** button appear on products that are **Out of stock**.

1. Set System->Configuration->Catalog->Inventory->Backorders=**Allow Qty Below 0**
2. Set System->Configuration->Catalog->Inventory->Stock Options->Display Out of Stock Products=**Yes**
3. Since Magento will not allow you to change the **Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock** option to go bellow 0 (cannot put a negative value) it is necessary to run the following SQL statement from your phpmyadmin panel:

   > UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = '-1' WHERE `path` = 'cataloginventory/item_options/min_qty';
4. Verify the setting has been added: System->Configuration->Catalog->Inventory verify that **Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock** is now **-1** (negative one)
5. Set all store products to **In stock**: Catalog->Manage Products, *Select all products* -> Select **"Actions"**->**Update Attributes** -> Submit, Select **Inventory** -> Stock Availability = **In Stock** -> **SAVE**
6. Re-index all indexes.
7. Now that all products are **In Stock** and we now have a new rule for that will only set the products **Out of stock** when the value goes bellow zero (our setting is -1 [minus one]) it is now necessary to modify the theme in the front end.

**list.phtml** and **view.phtml** both contain **IF** statements that create a condition that if the product is **"In Stock"** then display the **Add to cart**, **this needs to be removed now that the site has been modified in order to display for all products**.

**Example:**

**This code**

```
<div class="add-to-box">
  <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>     
  <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

**Becomes this**

```
<div class="add-to-box">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
</div>
```

An alternative way to display out of stock and In stock using **QTY** and not **stock status**:

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct() ?>
<?php if((int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty() < 1): ?>
<p><strong>
  <?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?>
</strong></p>
<?php else: ?>
<p>
  <?php echo $this->__('In Stock')?>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Very surprised that it is this time consuming to allow visitors to purchase products that are out of stock. Hope this helps someone and you won't need to use your bounty to get it done.

Comment: See @TBI-Infotech's answer. That's the correct way to do it. Attempting to hack Magento with your config update is only going to cause you problems in the future.

Comment: @JoeConstant look at the date and time of the post - your 2 years late. At the time this WAS the best way to achieve this. Thanks for the down vote! I highly suggest you READ and take everything into considerations before voting.

Comment: Even 2 years ago that would not be an acceptable solution.

Comment: Whatever makes you feel better :)

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately, you are not missing a step here. Normally, people would think that the following two configuration options are enough to make it happen:

1. Set `System - Configuration - Catalog - Inventory - Stock Options - Display Out of Stock Products` to `Yes`.
2. Set `System - Configuration - Catalog - Inventory - Product Stock Options - Backorder` to `Allow Qty Below 0`.

<sup>You of course also have to make sure that the same settings are set in the specific product or that the product is configured to use the config settings.</sup>

Unfortunately, this is not true. So that it really works, the availability of the product has to be set to `In Stock`. Otherwise, Magento will not show the add to cart button and will not let you buy the product.
This alone would maybe not be a problem if you could configure Magento not to set the product to `Out of Stock` each time it is ordered and falls below the `Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock` barrier. But this is not possible. For the smart guys out here: No, it is also not possible to set this setting to a quantity below 0 via the admin settings.

Possibilities:

1. You could fix the issue that the product is set to `Out of Stock` by fixing the config entry in the database: `` UPDATE `core_config_data` SET  `value` = '-9999' WHERE `path` = 'cataloginventory/item_options/min_qty'; ``. Although this then applies to all products, not only to the ones which are configured for backorders.
2. You could try [one](https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Pre-Order.html) [of the](http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/backorder.html) ["Preorder"](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/pre-order-by-amasty.html) or ["Backorder"](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/backorder.html) extensions.
3. You could set the product to `In Stock` manually each time such an order occurs (of course only possible for very rare cases).

Comment: I appreciate the answer and I as you pointed out I am not alone. I do not want to pay for an extension, I'm positive that someone out there will chime in with the solution since this affects anyone running magento.

Comment: I doubt it, because I think it is a major intrusion at a critical part of the system. And the extensions are not really expensive. But anyway, of course you can leave it open and look what happens :) Cheers

Comment: I have no issue purchasing extensions and have purchased many; my issue is that there should be no reason for this configuration **not to work**. Why would there be options to allow back orders and no way to allow them? SR

Comment: I totally agree! I [pinged some Magento community guys](https://twitter.com/SimonSprankel/status/499893893325127681). Let us see if this helps :)

Comment: Appreciate it, wish I could give you another plus 1 :)

Comment: I've awarded you the bounty because you provided a lot of great information that helped guide me to the answer. Thanks for your help! SR

Answer (score 2):

There is an option available in admin.

Just go to your manage product page and in `inventory tab` you can find

> Backorders dropdown

, choose allow quantity below 0 option and save, now customer can order out of stock product also.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to configure your store to display out of stock products:

Go to `System > Configuration > Catalog | Inventory > Stock Options` and set `Display Out of Stock Products` to *Yes*

Comment: This is already set and is not displaying the add to cart button. Thanks for the quick reply, let me know if you think of anything else :)

Comment: As the last option you can set "manage stock" to "no" for the product.

Comment: @Amasty this indicates incorrectly indicates that the product is in stock when it is not. I'm surprised that this isn't an easy fix.

Comment: Some webshops use custom stock statuses for this. You can modify your view.phtml to warn customers.  And yes, handling backorders or preorders is tricky in magento, that is why there are many extensions for this.

Comment: I'll give it some time - hopefully someone can come up with something thanks :)

Comment: Usually changing those options require reindexing as well.

Comment: "Display Out of Stock Products to Yes" - Yes but the whole point is to show it for 'Out Of Stock' products isn't it...?