# Update available shipping methods & recalulate tax

Tags: checkout, cart, magento-1.9, tax

In continuation of my post [Add items to cart by link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32359/add-to-cart-by-url-and-error-handling-on-1-9) post the other day:
When posting the customer's zip code and getting back the available shipping options, the tax rate is not updated.

Code to update zip code in cart:

```
include_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');


// Change to your postcode / country.
$zipcode = $_POST["ZIPCODENEW"];
$country = 'US';
$shipstate = $_POST["STATE"];


// Update the cart's quote.
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$address = $cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();

$address->setCountryId($country)
        ->setPostcode($zipcode)
        ->setRegionId($shipstate)
        ->setCollectShippingRates(true);


$cart->save();
```

This works as intended, and can be verified with magento's cart page that shipping options were returned. These shipping methods are also available via the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934138/magento-get-all-shipping-rates).

What this does not do is recalculate tax. If I go to the magento shopping cart and put in a zip code to get the available shipping rates, and use a zip code that falls under a tax rule then tax is automatically recalculated.

Now here's the rub: If I update the totals of an item from my cart (after tax has been applied by the Magento checkout), then the tax total is correctly updated. Additionally, if I get tax from the magento shopping cart, then have my cart change the zip to a non-tax zone (using the above code), the tax is correctly removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We actually solved this, and I feel silly for missing it, and being the one that solved it.

Magento passes the sate as numbers, rather than 2-letter abbreviations. For some reason the system will accept, then discard the two letter abbreviations, but still give full/correct shipping quotes from the zip code. As soon as we passed the state variable correctly the taxes updated as expected.

You can see the state<->ID# relationship by examining the HTML form on the normal shopping cart.

You can also get this list directly from magento:

```
$states = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load('US')->getRegions();
```

Then you can set your HTML form something like this:

```
<?php foreach ($states as $state): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $state->getId(); ?>"><?php echo $state->getName(); ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```