# Purchase of out of stock items

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, out-of-stock

Title is self explanatory.
Recently I have changed all items of a certain brand as out of stock and the very next day a person purchased two product from this brand. My question is what could have caused this issue?

It is important to notice that

- all items of this brand have 0 qty
- all of them have stock vause as out of stock
- I cannot see items from this brand on front end neither when browsing through categories nor when using search

Could a possible reason this could have happend be that a person had these items in their cart before I marked them as out of stock, or could he has purchased them via google cached page?

This has happened in the past and past research didn't give me much, so I created this question. Could not find any questions that would be similar too.

Answer (score 1):

Magento will not allow you to change the Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock option to go bellow 0.
For more detail Just Check This [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31849/add-to-cart-for-out-of-stock-products).